# Is Bypassing App Store Payment possible?

Tags: ios

Much similar to what Comixology did 4 days back in http://www.theverge.com/2014/4/26/5656468/comixology-ios-update-removes-in-app-purchases removing In App purchases; I am exploring web based subscription as well.

But in case of Comixology once customer subscribes on website; comics are downloaded into Apps from its own servers. In my case I want my App to show other Apps which are in iTunes Appstore . Basically my App will show 'ten must have apps'.

Can I do what Comixology did? Or mine is a different case since its not my own server feeding content but Appstore feeding content?

Comment: Where does the list of apps come from?  These must come from your own server?  Would the process be user visits your web site, registers/pays then runs app & provides userid/password to app and then app displays "ten must have apps"?  As long as the client cannot register from your app but only log in then you are probably OK.

Comment: Yes. You are right about the user experience. Here it is in more detail.

My app will be a parent app. Parent app will indicate that the user has not downloaded the other ten apps from Apple Appstore. The parent will have ten links. Once the user downloads each of those 10 free apps (or few of them) the user can start using those apps.

Since those 10 apps are coming from app store, the question I have is that dont I have to offer Apple a cut? Since they are just authenticating I take your answer as I am OK with the approach.

Comment: So, use of the "parent app" is unlocked when the users download the other apps?

Comment: Just to clarify again, all the apps are coming from Apple Appstore. is this still valid?

Comment: Clarifying Paulw11's earlier question - For each of the 10 apps, unless they are downloaded the App Link will say 'install from Appstore' if already downloaded the link will say 'use the app'.

The parent app is updated as and when the download of other 10 apps take place. I plan to maintain the state of download of other apps using my own server/database.

Is this still valid by Apple?

Comment: Really, only Apple can tell you when you submit your app.  If apps are coming from the app store are either free or paid for via the app store, then Apple cannot object to that, but I don't really understand how this applies to the Comixology example.  In that case you subscribe to content through a web site and then consume it through the app.  In your case "payment" appears to be installing specified apps, in which case I can't see how Apple can object on in-app purchasing grounds.  They may have an issue with the overall user experience which sounds pretty ghastly to me